# smoke JS with OK and Cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, smoke

does anyone know how make a smoke.js return a value. For example if I select "OK" the value should return true, and if I select Cancel, the value should be false.

```
function check() {
if (smoke.confirm("Are you sure?", function (e) { })) {
      return true
   }
   return false;
}
```

I also tried this code. It output the value properly but it is not being return by the function

```
smoke.confirm("Are you sure？", function (e) {
  alert(e);
  return e;
});
```

Help please

Comment: take a look in the sourcecode from the demo. Search for 'e'. Look at the DISCO sample